# markdown inline preview like it is done with preview-latex

Tags: markdown-mode

I am completely new to markdown and would like to know if there is any package/mode which allows to live preview only parts of the document (mainly equations, tables and images) like it is possible with preview-latex?

Until now, I could only see the preview in a different buffer.

Thanks!
Fab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`texfrag-mode`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag). It can be installed from [melpa](https://melpa.org/#/texfrag).

After installation customize the variable `texfrag-setup-alist` by adding `markdown-mode` to the entry for `texfrag-trac-wiki`.

Afterwards you can open your markdown file and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `texfrag-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Therewith you get the `preview-latex` menu as `TeX` in the menu bar.

If you always want to turn on `texfrag-mode` for a specific document you can run `texfrag-mode` in the local variables.

Example:

```markdown
# Some Heading

Test of formula: $y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

We also include a picture:
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{picture}(30,30)
        \put(15,15){Test}
        \put(15,15){\circle{15}}
    \end{picture}
  \caption{First picture.}
\end{figure}

[//]: # Local Variables:
[//]: # eval: (texfrag-mode)
[//]: # End:
```

The buffer looks like follows after hitting <kbd>C-c C-p C-d</kbd>.

[image: TeXfrag Preview]

If you want to run `texfrag-mode` for all your markdown files you can add the following line to your init file:

```el
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'texfrag-mode)
```

With that configuration you don't need the local variables section from the last example.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, this seems exactly what I am looking for. Actually, I getting the setup so far to get the TeX menu for my markdown buffer, but running the C-c-C-p-C-d command for previewing will not do anything.  Showin texfrag-log just says that nothing is running; I have a working preview-latex setup on macos with spacemacs. I am not sure, if I should ask further here or jump to the texfrag issues on github? Thank you very much!

Comment: ok, this works now, I am not sure, what I did different now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options to achieve this, from within emacs you can can simply use `org-toggle-latex-fragment` which is the simplest solution, putting the following into your `~/emacs.d/init.el` file will fix the binding to `C-c C-x C-l` just like it is in org-mode:

```
 (add-hook 'mardkown-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-l") 'org-toggle-latex-fragment)
     (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x C-u") 'markdown-toggle-url-hiding)
     ))
```

My current solution is to basically manage all my notes in [VNote](https://github.com/tamlok/vnote) and org-mode and then build them with [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) to read them on a server / gitpage on my phone. So I'll edit them in emacs, manage them in Vnote and then if I want to include some math I usually use vim with a plugin.

Another option is to use one of the markdown preview packages that are available, the [doom starter kit](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/StarterKits) (which I'm using atm) includes one but I don't use it.

An easier option is to use [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk?hl=en) in conjuction with a local server (e.g. `python3 -m http.server`) and view the files in the browser, this also means links will work. It would also be possible to build the markdown with [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc), tie that to a keybinding and then view the HTML in the browser seperately.

I usually write my markdown and LaTeX in vim because the [snippets](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) are better and I'll use [this function](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vim-current-buffer) to open vim from emacs, if that's something you're interested in then I'd recommend [this plugin](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vim-current-buffer).

If you don't like any of that you could use the live preview offered by [Marktext](https://github.com/marktext/marktext), [Zettlr](https://www.zettlr.com/), [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Typora](https://typora.io/) and simply edit the source in markdown.

I would really recommend looking at VNote though, It's become indispensable to me.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the texfrag-mode seems exactly what I need.

Comment: Thank you. Since Org 9.3 `org-toggle-latex-fragment` is obsolete and `org-latex-preview` should be used.